# 2-dimensional invariant subspace using Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, invariance, invariant-subspace

If given a matrix which is invertible, and knowing the Jordan canonical form is:
$$J = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0&5&0&0\\0&0&-8&0\\0&0&0&8\end{bmatrix}$$
How do you go about finding the two dimensional invariant subspaces?

Comment: Every 2D invariant subspace for this operator will be a direct sum of two 1D eigenspaces.

Comment: @runway44, ok so in order to determine the 1D eigenspaces I need to calculate the eigenvalues, then my eigenspaces are the eigenvectors? Then it would just be the sum of two of the eigenspaces which gives the subspace?

Comment: Yes. Except you don't need to calculate the eigenvalues, because you already know they are $-2$, $5$, $-8$, $8$.